# How to set CORS headers into internal server error responses?

Tags: java, jax-rs, cors, resteasy

I have a java application server with a REST interface provided by resteasy and I have the CORS filter bellow

```
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext cReq, ContainerResponseContext cResp) {
        cResp.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        cResp.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization, auth-token");
        cResp.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        cResp.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        cResp.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
    }

}
```

All requests return with the CORS headers:

```
OPTIONS 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:"true"
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:"origin, content-type, accept, authorization, auth-token"
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:"GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:"*"
Access-Control-Max-Age:"1209600"
Allow:"HEAD, GET, OPTIONS"
Connection:"keep-alive"
Content-Length:"18"
Content-Type:"text/plain"
Date:"Thu, 15 Jan 2015 15:23:01 GMT"
Server:"WildFly/8"
```

except when I have an internal exception that returns error code 500:

```
GET 500 Internal Server Error
Connection:"keep-alive"
Content-Length:"8228"
Content-Type:"text/html; charset=UTF-8"
Date:"Thu, 15 Jan 2015 15:23:01 GMT"
```

How can I make 500 responses contain those headers?

Comment: Note that browsers often don't like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in combination with `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` - if you want to allow credentials then you should allow a specific origin rather than `*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [ExceptionMapper](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html):

```
@Provider
public class CorsExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception ex) {
        ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.serverError();
        responseBuilder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responseBuilder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization, auth-token");
        responseBuilder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        responseBuilder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        responseBuilder.header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
        return responseBuilder.build();
    }

}
```

To avoid duplication of headers you should use:

```
cResp.getHeaders().putSingle()
```

In the `ContainerResponseFilter`.

Comment: I was going to suggest this, but after testing, what I realized is that if the exception is thrown in a JAX-RS context, it will still go through the response filter. So the headers will still be there. If we add the exception mapper, it will actually double up the headers. If the OP is facing a problem with the headers not appearing, then the exception may be occurring outside the JAX-RS scope and may need to be handled somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks! This is annoying. Maybe the easiest solution is to use `cResp.getHeaders().putSingle()` in the `ContainerResponseFilter`?

Comment: That should override it huh? Haven't checked, but seems right.

Comment: Yes: `Set the key's value to be a one item list consisting of the supplied value. Any existing values will be replaced.`

Comment: I used your provided code but all parameters were being replicated in the header, so I just omitted the header() calls and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The ExceptionMapper will not work in all scenario's I've found. There seem to be some other container responses for which we need yet another filter type. Especially the response to requests to `j_security_check` (FORM login) [don't get CORS headers added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217936/add-cors-headers-to-response-of-j-security-check). So instead of using both a `ContainerResponseFilter` and an `ExceptionMapper` and still having some responses without CORS headers, I've opted for an Undertow filter. The downside is that it only works on Undertow-based servers (Jboss EAP, Wildfly, Wildfly Swarm), but the upside is that it works for *all* responses.

I wrote a specific filter for adding CORS headers that is installed as a JBoss Module and is configurable from `standalone.xml`. Find it here:

### [undertow-cors-filter](https://github.com/download/undertow-cors-filter)

Download the .zip file and unzip it in your Wildfly root folder. Then add a `filter` configuration to `standalone.xml`:

```
<filters>
  <filter name="undertow-cors-filter" class-name="com.stijndewitt.undertow.cors.Filter" module="com.stijndewitt.undertow.cors">
    <param name="urlPattern" value="^http(s)?://([^/]+)(:([^/]+))?(/([^/])+)?/api(/.*)?$" />
    <param name="policyClass" value="com.stijndewitt.undertow.cors.AllowMatching" />
    <param name="policyParam" value="^http(s)?://(www\.)?example\.(com|org)$" />   
  </filter>
</filters>
```

Add a `filter-ref` to the `host` element (still in `standalone.xml`):

```
<host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
  <filter-ref name="undertow-cors-filter" />
</host>
```

This will add CORS headers allowing origins http(s)://(www.)example.(com|org) access to all responses for requests to URLs under path segment `"/api"`.

Change the `param`s in the `filter` definition to configure the behavior. There are 3 policy classes available, `AllowAll`, `AllowMatching` and `Whitelist` and you can write your own custom policies if needed.