# Add CORS headers to response of j_security_check

Tags: jakarta-ee, cors, wildfly, j-security-check

I'm building a **REST API** with jax-rs and **WildFly 10**. Some of the endpoints are secured. I'm using **FORM** based authentication.

In my javascript code, I check the response of the `AJAX` request, and if it is set to `401 Unauthorized`, I then present a login form to the user. When he fills it in, I POST the details to `j_security_check`.

Running on `localhost` this all works fine, but when the webserver and the REST server are on different machines, the browser denies the AJAX request due to cross-origin issues.

I understand CORS, so I added a CORS filter to my REST server that sets CORS headers for the GUI server. It all works fine, except for one small, but important detail: after the login has succeeded, the CORS filter does not fire for the `j_security_check` response. No CORS headers are added and the browser can not read the response.

Apart from this one detail I have the whole setup working exactly like I want it.... But I have been struggling with this detail all night and I just can't get it to work.

I understand there are issues with trying to filter `j_security_check`, but I know of no other ways to add CORS headers... So my question is:

**How do I add CORS headers to the response for `j_security_check`?**

Comment: Hi! I’ve faced exactly the same problem while implementing `ContainerResponseFilter`.  I’m able to add all the needed `Access-Control-Allow-XXX` headers to any response on the server side. But response to the `j_security_check` request is an exception. Have you managed to find the solution? Thank in advance:).

Comment: Yeah... sort of. Not really happy with it but it sort of works. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuring `undertow` subsystem in `standalone.xml`/`domain.xml` file solved this problem for me. Filters configured there handle all the requests including `j_security_check` one.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" redirect-socket="https" socket-binding="http"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                    <!--CORS headers -->
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Max-Age"/>
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            </handlers>
            <filters>
                <response-header name="server-header" header-value="WildFly/10" header-name="Server"/>
                <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-value="Undertow/1" header-name="X-Powered-By"/>
                <!-- CORS headers -->
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-value="*"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header-value="OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header-value="accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" header-value="true"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Max-Age" header-name="Access-Control-Max-Age" header-value="60"/>
            </filters>
        </subsystem>
```

Of course you'd better replace `"*"` wildcard by your GUI server's url in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header's value attribute.

Comment: What a great solution:)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, multiple domains are not allowed as cors origin value. Neither is `*`. And you can't have multiple cors origin headers in one response... This effectively means you cannot use static config like this if you have multiple domains (as most sites have that support both naked domain urls and ones starting with *www.*)

Comment: @nfedorov Well it's one and a half year later and in that time I did a lot of research on this subject and it seems you are 100% right. The way you describe here with an Undertow filter seems to be the only way to filter these requests. Servlet filters and JAX-RS filters do not get called for these requests.

Comment: To solve the problem with the value for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` having to be dynamic, I created an Undertow filter specifically for adding CORS headers. I will add an answer about it.

Comment: @nfedorov, I still get "Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed". What do I need to modify to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

**Handle the login yourself**.

Instead of posting to `j_security_check`, post to `/auth/login` or something like that and handle the login. Something like this:

```
@POST
@Path("login")
@PermitAll
public Response postLogin() {
    String user = request.getParameter("j_username");
    String password = request.getParameter("j_password");
    StringBuffer buf = request.getRequestURL();
    URI redir = null; 
    try {redir = new URI(buf.substring(0, buf.lastIndexOf("/login")) + "/session");} 
    catch (URISyntaxException e) {}
    try {
        request.login(user, password);
        return Response.seeOther(redir).build();
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        if (e.getMessage() != null && e.getMessage().equals("UT010030: User already logged in")) {
            Response.seeOther(redir).build();
        }
        return Response.status(Status.FORBIDDEN).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not accepting this answer, because it is actually a workaround... then again it may be the only way. Who knows? Still hoping for more input from the SO community.

Comment: [undertow-cors-filter](https://github.com/download/undertow-cors-filter) is probably the best way to handle this atm.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [nfedorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6758880/nfedorov)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39189545/286685), I came to the conclusion that he is right and that an Undertow filter is the only type of filter that can operate on container responses. So if we want to add CORS headers to these responses, we need an Undertow filter. So I wrote one:

### [undertow-cors-filter](https://github.com/download/undertow-cors-filter)

Download the .zip file and unzip it in your Wildfly root folder. Then add a `filter` configuration to `standalone.xml`:

```
<filters>
  <filter name="undertow-cors-filter" class-name="com.stijndewitt.undertow.cors.Filter" module="com.stijndewitt.undertow.cors">

  </filter>
</filters>
```

Add a `filter-ref` to the `host` element (still in `standalone.xml`):

```
<host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
  <filter-ref name="undertow-cors-filter" />
</host>
```

This will add CORS headers allowing all origins access to all responses this server emits.

Add `param`s to the `filter` definition to configure the behavior. For example, if you want the filter to apply only to responses for requests to URLS starting with `/api` and you only want to allow example.com and example.org access, you could use a configuration similar to this:

```
<filters>
  <filter name="undertow-cors-filter" class-name="com.stijndewitt.undertow.cors.Filter" module="com.stijndewitt.undertow.cors">
    <param name="urlPattern" value="^http(s)?://([^/]+)(:([^/]+))?(/([^/])+)?/api(/.*)?$" />
    <param name="policyClass" value="com.stijndewitt.undertow.cors.AllowMatching" />
    <param name="policyParam" value="^http(s)?://(www\.)?example\.(com|org)$" />   
  </filter>
</filters>
```

There are 3 policy classes available, `AllowAll`, `AllowMatching` and `Whitelist` and you can write your own custom policies if needed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the earlier answer by nfedorov, configuring undertow subsystem in standalone.xml/domain.xml file would solve this problem.
But that suggested solution would only allow either one domain or '*' to be specified in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header's value attribute. Slightly better solution would be to whitelist one or more domains for accessing the REST APIs, if the APIs could potentially be accessed from more than one domain. We could achieve the whitelisting and matching the requesting domain against the whitelist in Undertow without using any 3rd party Undertow Filter. Undertow Predicates & Exchange Attributes would help achieve this. A regex can be used to define the list of domains to be whitelisted. And the CORS related response header Access-Control-Allow-Origin could be written to the response conditionally by checking the incoming Origin header and matching it against the whitelist using regex matching. All these could be configured in the standalone.xml of Wildfly without any Java coding. The following article explains the same.

https://medium.com/amritatech/a-mechanism-to-enable-cors-filter-with-no-coding-57ef2906e023

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).