# CORSFilter internal error

Tags: servlets, server, servlet-filters

I use this library

http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-configuration.html

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>authorization,content-type,x-http-method-override</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
        <param-value>1800</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>authorization</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
```

All work fine

except when I have an internal exception that returns error code 500:

```
content-length:10226
content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
date:Sun, 30 Apr 2017 21:44:29 GMT
status:500
```

GET 500 Internal Server Error

How can I make 500 responses contain those headers?

Comment: Does anybody now?

Comment: I find answer Without CORSFilter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968190/how-to-set-cors-headers-into-internal-server-error-responses